# Trigger a Notebook Instance in AWS SageMaker using AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

I want to start a Notebook instance and execute the Jupyter notebook within the instance using AWS S3. That being said, as long as there is a file in S3, the notebook will be triggered and executed, and the corresponding output will be exported to S3 automatically. Can this be achieved? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use EventBridge and Lambda function to start a notebook instance based on an event (like a file upload to S3, se example here - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-dynamic-amazon-s3-event-handling-with-amazon-eventbridge/), and execute the notebook (sample LCC to execute notebook on startup - https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples/tree/master/scripts/execute-notebook-on-startup)

That said, I'd recommend using SageMaker jobs, since they automatically shutdown once the code is executed. If you're using notebook instances, you also have to shut down the notebooks.

Also, make sure you're using different S3 buckets/prefixes for input and output files, otherwise, the writing output file will trigger the Lambda function and will stay looping.

Comment: Thank you. Let me implement it from my end today and I will keep you posted.

Comment: Yup, I am able to do it by triggering a Lambda function using an event pattern, and select ```simple storage service``` option. Then create a rule using EventBridge following https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-use-amazon-s3-event-notifications-with-amazon-eventbridge/

Comment: In addition, we also can automatically shut down any notebook instance by creating an LCC.